# Cannot call reactReduxFirebase() - TypeError: Object is not a function

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, react-redux-firebase, redux-firestore

I an using `redux-thunk` as a middleware and trying to connect to `redux-firestore`. When I run the application I am getting the error **"TypeError: Object(...) is not a function"** at `createStore`.

```
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import {createStore,applyMiddleware,compose} from 'redux';
import rootReducer from './store/reducers/rootReducer';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import {reduxFirestore, getFirestore} from 'redux-firestore'
import {reactReduxFirebase, getFirebase} from 'react-redux-firebase'
import FBConfig from './Config/FBConfig'

const store = createStore(rootReducer,
  compose(applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({getFirestore,getFirebase})),
    reduxFirestore(FBConfig),
    reactReduxFirebase(FBConfig)
  )
);
```

I am using the extra arguments in my thunk actions like this:

```
export const createProject=(project)=>{
      return(dispatch,getState,{getFirebase,getFirestore})=>{
            //asyn call to database
            const firestore=getFirestore();
            firestore.collection('projects').add({
                  ...project,
                  authorFirstName:'Nam',
                  authorLastName:'Pam',
                  authorId:123,
                  createAt: new Date()
            }).then(()=>{
                  dispatch({type:'CREATE_PROJECT',project});
                  
            }).catch((err)=>{
                  dispatch({type:'CREATE_PROJECT_ERROR',err})
            })  
      }
};
```

Comment: Can you share the full stack trace?

Comment: Edited with the action.js code.

Comment: The error seems to be on `reactReduxFirebase(FBConfig)` as `reactReduxFirebase` is not a function.  It seems like you want to use `getFirebase` instead and pass the function itself rather than calling the function: http://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/integrations/thunks.html

Comment: Looks like `reactReduxFirebase` used to be a function but was removed in v3 of `react-redux-firebase`: http://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/v3-migration-guide.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error that you are seeing is likely due to upgrading `react-redux-firebase` [from v2 to v3](http://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/v3-migration-guide.html) (or basing new code on outdated examples).  This update introduced some breaking changes such as the removal of the `reactReduxFirebase` store enhancer function.  The package now uses React contexts and introduced some new hooks such as `useFirebase` and `useFirestore` which allow you to access firebase through the context in function components.  But that doesn't help with your thunk.

In the page on [Redux Thunk Integration](http://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/integrations/thunks.html), they recommend passing the `getFirebase` function to the `withExtraArgument`.

```
thunk.withExtraArgument(getFirebase)
```

As far as accessing firestore, [this GitHub discussion](https://github.com/prescottprue/react-redux-firebase/issues/785) recommends accessing it through the `getFirebase` function.

```
getFirebase().firestore()
```

You want your extra argument to be an object with properties `getFirebase` and `getFirestore`.  We use `getFirebase` as one property and create an inline arrow function for the `getFirestore` property.

```
import {createStore,applyMiddleware, AnyAction} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import {getFirebase} from 'react-redux-firebase';

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(
    thunk.withExtraArgument({
      getFirebase,
      getFirestore: () => getFirebase().firestore(),
    })
  )
);
```